# PHP substr echoes incorrect characters

Tags: php

I have a string:

> ‘I’m Part of a big MNC’: Tips on how you can rise to the top position.

I want the substring: **‘I’m Part**

The string is stored in a variable called `$title`

My code:

```
<?php echo substr( $title, 0, 9 ); ?>
```

It returns `‘I’m` on [writephponline](http://www.writephponline.com/)

and on webpage, it returns `‘I&`

Any reason why this happens?

Comment: I got same in webpage and writephponline. output i got is : `‘I’m`

Comment: just a hunch but the encoding of the `‘` character is liable to be the problem

Answer (score 2):

The issue here comes from the fact that [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) doesn't count characters but bytes.

Your input string is multi-byte; one character is represented on one or more bytes. The exact amount depends on the encoding of the string. Most probably it is `UTF-8` but only you can tell it for sure.

Anyway, the solution to your problem is the [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) function which is part of the [PHP mb extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

Answer (score 1):

The problem will be with the quotes you are using in your original string.

If you use regular single quotes `'`, the correct output will be presented:

```
$title = "'I'm Part of a big MNC': Tips on how you can rise to the top position.";
echo substr( $title, 0, 9 );
```

Result:

```
'I'm Part
```

Comment: Changing the input to match the code is not a solution. Maybe the input string comes from the user and in this case it can contain anything.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your data isn't ASCII. you have to use multibyte-functions and tell PHP to use the correct encoding, probably UTF-8, internally.

this example worked as expected in writephponline:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$string = "‘I’m Part of a big MNC’";
var_dump(mb_substr($string, 0, 9));
//output:  string(13) "‘I’m Part"
```